# textview on arraylist Android

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

My "stress" is place a **hyperlink on a item of ArrayList**. Dont have any TextView on XML, only a simple ListView.

```
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    //header 
    listDataHeader.add("Text Example");
    //itens
    List<String> ItemAL = new ArrayList<String>();
    ItemAL .add("Text Example");
    ItemAL .add(**"Watch Clip - http://videos.sapo.pt/testtesttest**");
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), ItemAL );
}
```

And my XML FILE:

```
<RelativeLayout...
    <ListView
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/lvExp4"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_checked" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What adapter are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all create adapter for your listview,and set textview as per your requirements and then

use this property in your textview attribute :-

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom base adapter with a layout file for a particular list item. The text view which you need hyperlink can be made by using either spannable using underline span or painting the textview.